# Clarification on the flow of realtime work to a GPU

Tags: cuda, gpu

I just started learning CUDA, and I am confused by one point. For the sake of argument, imagine that I had several hundred buoys in the ocean. Imagine that they broadcast a std::vector intermittently once every few milliseconds. The vector might be 5 readings, or 10 readings, etc, depending on the conditions in the ocean at that time. There is no way to tell when the event will fire, it is not deterministic.

Imagine that I had the idea that I could predict the temperature from gathering all this information in realtime, but that the predictor had to first sort all std::vectos on temperature accross all buoy. My question is this. Do I have to copy the entire data back to the GPU every time a single buyoy fires an event? Since the other buoy's data has not changed, can I leave that data in the GPU and just update what has changed and ask the kernel to rerun the prediction?

If yes, what is the [thrust pseudo]-code that would do this?  Is this best done with streams and events and pinned memory? What is the limit as to how fast I can update the GPU with realtime data?

I was told that this sort of problem is not well suited to GPU and better in FPGA.

Comment: You are right in saying that this problem is better suited for FPGAs.

Comment: A few questions.  For demonstration, can we limit the number of buoys to some known value?  Also, can we limit the maximum number of temperature samples that will be received from a single buoy in a single update to some known value?  And when a buoy fires a new set of values, is it *replacing* an older set of values, or is it simply adding to the overall set of values that need to be sorted and then processed (suggesting that the problem grows indefinitely).  And when you say sort all std::vectors, do you mean individually sort each, or combine all into a single large vector and sort that?

Comment: Thank you for all your comments. Robert, yes I need to clarify. Yes, the number of buoys are fixed and known. Yes, the maximum size of the individual vector is known. When the buoy fires a new vector, that vector replaces the old vector, but now the temperature sort is invalid across all buoy. Sort I mean accross all vectors. They are already sorted within each  individual vector.

Comment: Jack, the thing is that the prediction is computationally expensive.True ,there is not much data, but there is a huge combinatorial problem. Imagine the prediction entailed a kind of graph algorithm like Dijkstra's algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A basic sequence could be like this.

Setup phase (initial sort):

1. Gather an initial set of vectors from each buoy.
2. Create a parallel set of vectors, one for each buoy, of length equal to the initial length of the buoy vector, and popluated by the buoy index:

   ```
   b1:  1.5 1.7 2.2 2.3 2.6
   i1:    1   1   1   1   1
   b2:  2.4 2.5 2.6
   i2:    2   2   2
   b3:  2.8
   i3:    3
   ```
3. Concatenate all vectors into a single buoy-temp-vector and buoy-index-vector:

   ```
   b:  1.5 1.7 2.2 2.3 2.6 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.8
   i:    1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2   3
   ```
4. [Sort-by-key](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__sorting.html#ga2bb765aeef19f6a04ca8b8ba11efff24):

   ```
   b:  1.5 1.7 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.5 2.6 2.6 2.8
   i:    1   1   1   1   2   2   1   2   3
   ```

The setup phase is complete.  The update phase is executed whenever a buoy update is received.  Suppose buoy `2` sends an update:

```
b2:  2.5 2.7 2.9 3.0
```

1. Do [thrust::remove_if](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__stream__compaction.html#ga5fa8f86717696de88ab484410b43829b) on the buoy vector, if the corresponding index vector position holds the updated buoy number (`2` in this case).  Repeat the `remove_if` on the index vector using the same rule:

   ```
   b:  1.5 1.7 2.2 2.3 2.6 2.8
   i:    1   1   1   1   1   3
   ```
2. Generate the corresponding index vector for the buoy to be updated, and copy both vectors (buoy `2` temp-value and index vectors) to the device:

   ```
   b2: 2.5 2.7 2.9 3.0
   i2:   2   2   2   2
   ```
3. Do [thrust::merge_by_key](http://thrust.github.io/doc/group__merging.html#gaca072577ee54cb35da588205530e026c) on the newly received update from buoy `2`

   ```
   b: 1.5 1.7 2.2 2.3 2.5 2.6 2.7 2.8 2.9 3.0
   i:   1   1   1   1   2   1   2   3   2   2
   ```

The only data that has to be copied to the device on an update cycle is the actual buoy data to be updated.  Note that with some work, the setup phase could be eliminated, and the initial assembly of the vectors could be merely seen as "updates" from each buoy, into initially-empty buoy value and buoy index vectors.  But for description, it's easier to visualize with a setup phase, I think.  The above description doesn't explicitly point out the various vector sizings and resizings needed, but this can be accomplished using the same methods one would use on `std::vector`.  Vector resizing may be "costly" on the GPU, just as it can be "costly" on the CPU (if a resize to larger triggers a new allocation and copy...) but this could also be elmiminated if a max number of buoys is known and a max number of elements per update is known.  In that case, we could allocate our overall buoy value and buoy index vector to be the maximum necessary sizes.

Here is a fully-worked example following the above outline.  As a placeholder, I have included a dummy `prediction_kernel` call, showing where you could insert your specialized prediction code, operating on the sorted data.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/sort.h>
#include <thrust/merge.h>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <time.h>

#define N_BUOYS 1024
#define N_MAX_UPDATE 1024
#define T_RANGE 100
#define N_UPDATES_TEST 1000

struct equal_func{

  const int idx;

  equal_func(int _idx) : idx(_idx) {}

  __host__ __device__
  bool operator()(int test_val) {
    return (test_val == idx);
  }
};

__device__ float dev_result[N_UPDATES_TEST];

// dummy "prediction" kernel
__global__ void prediction_kernel(const float *data, int iter, size_t d_size){
    int idx=threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x;
    if (idx == 0) dev_result[iter] = data[d_size/2];
  }

void create_vec(unsigned int id, thrust::host_vector<float> &data, thrust::host_vector<int> &idx){
  size_t mysize = rand()%N_MAX_UPDATE;
  data.resize(mysize);
  idx.resize(mysize);
  for (int i = 0; i < mysize; i++){
    data[i] = ((float)rand()/(float)RAND_MAX)*(float)T_RANGE;
    idx[i] = id;}
  thrust::sort(data.begin(), data.end());
}

int main(){

  timeval t1, t2;
  int pp = 0;
// ping-pong processing vectors
  thrust::device_vector<float> buoy_data[2];
  buoy_data[0].resize(N_BUOYS*N_MAX_UPDATE);
  buoy_data[1].resize(N_BUOYS*N_MAX_UPDATE);
  thrust::device_vector<int>  buoy_idx[2];
  buoy_idx[0].resize(N_BUOYS*N_MAX_UPDATE);
  buoy_idx[1].resize(N_BUOYS*N_MAX_UPDATE);

// vectors for initial buoy data
  thrust::host_vector<float> h_buoy_data[N_BUOYS];
  thrust::host_vector<int> h_buoy_idx[N_BUOYS];

//SETUP
 // populate initial data
  int lidx=0;
  for (int i = 0; i < N_BUOYS; i++){
    create_vec(i, h_buoy_data[i], h_buoy_idx[i]);
    thrust::copy(h_buoy_data[i].begin(), h_buoy_data[i].end(), &(buoy_data[pp][lidx]));
    thrust::copy(h_buoy_idx[i].begin(), h_buoy_idx[i].end(), &(buoy_idx[pp][lidx]));
    lidx+= h_buoy_data[i].size();}
 // sort initial data
  thrust::sort_by_key(&(buoy_data[pp][0]), &(buoy_data[pp][lidx]), &(buoy_idx[pp][0]));


//UPDATE CYCLE
  gettimeofday(&t1, NULL);
  for (int i = 0; i < N_UPDATES_TEST; i++){
    unsigned int vec_to_update = rand()%N_BUOYS;
    int nidx = lidx - h_buoy_data[vec_to_update].size();
    create_vec(vec_to_update, h_buoy_data[vec_to_update], h_buoy_idx[vec_to_update]);
    thrust::remove_if(&(buoy_data[pp][0]), &(buoy_data[pp][lidx]), buoy_idx[pp].begin(), equal_func(vec_to_update));
    thrust::remove_if(&(buoy_idx[pp][0]), &(buoy_idx[pp][lidx]), equal_func(vec_to_update));
    lidx = nidx + h_buoy_data[vec_to_update].size();
    thrust::device_vector<float> temp_data = h_buoy_data[vec_to_update];
    thrust::device_vector<int> temp_idx = h_buoy_idx[vec_to_update];
    int ppn = (pp == 0)?1:0;
    thrust::merge_by_key(&(buoy_data[pp][0]), &(buoy_data[pp][nidx]), temp_data.begin(), temp_data.end(), buoy_idx[pp].begin(), temp_idx.begin(), buoy_data[ppn].begin(), buoy_idx[ppn].begin() );
    pp = ppn; // update ping-pong buffer index
    prediction_kernel<<<1,1>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(buoy_data[pp].data()), i, lidx);
  }
  gettimeofday(&t2, NULL);
  unsigned int tdiff_us = ((t2.tv_sec*1000000)+t2.tv_usec) - ((t1.tv_sec*1000000)+t1.tv_usec);
  printf("Completed %d updates in %f sec\n", N_UPDATES_TEST, (float)tdiff_us/(float)1000000);
//  float *temps = (float *)malloc(N_UPDATES_TEST*sizeof(float));
//  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(temps, dev_result, N_UPDATES_TEST*sizeof(float));
//  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) printf("temp %d: %f\n", i, temps[i]);
  return 0;

}
```

Using CUDA 6, on linux, on a Quadro 5000 GPU, 1000 "updates" requires about 2 seconds.  The majority of the time is spent in the calls to `thrust::remove_if` and `thrust::merge_by_key`  I suppose for worst case real-time estimation, you would want to try and time the worst case update, which might be something like receiving a longest-possible update.

Comment: Robert, Outstanding. That is terrific and I appreciate your thoroughness. I will go through your code carefully. I have a question, but I will keep it to myself until I am able to better to pose it. It pertains in the use of events and streams and pinned memory for [hoped] better performance....

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense to me.  The bulk of the activity in the update loop is about facilitating a sort.  If you want to sort on the CPU, then *everything* will be done on the CPU, meaning you won't be using the GPU at all.  I've given you a complete code.  You can do a quick test by changing every instance of `thrust::device_vector` to `thrust::host_vector` and re-run the test yourself.  You'll also need to comment out the kernel call.  That dummy kernel is doing nothing and taking no time in the above example.  I did those steps and the 1000 updates took 4.45 s instead of 2 s.

Comment: +1. So you have shown that the update phase is faster on the device than on the host, which was the main problem here. It is still not clear to me from the OP how many buoys are involved in the temperature prediction, but I have searched a bit around and I have found that the order of magnitude of deployed buoys is approximately equal to what you have considered in your algorithm, see the [USA National Data Buoy Center](http://www.ndbc.noaa.gov/).

Comment: I don't think the problem size representend in the example is optimal for demonstrating GPU speedup.  If I change it to 10000 buoys, the GPU time for 1000 updates is 10 seconds (only 5x slower), whereas the CPU version requires 40 seconds (almost 10x slower).  That is then approaching the memory bandwidth ratio, which I would expect to be the primary determinant of the speedup ratio, although niether CPU nor GPU implementation of this example would be expected to approach the actual peak memory bandwidth available.

Comment: Robert, I ran the code (minus the timings) under windows 7 pro visual studio 12 and it crashes. Using a Nvidia 640 with 2GB. Throws memory exception even if I reduce all the consts to very small numbers. I am going to try it under linux next.

Comment: #define N_BUOYS 32
#define N_MAX_UPDATE 32 buoy_data[0].resize(N_BUOYS * N_MAX_UPDATE); This single line takes a really long time.

Comment: Sorry, all these problems were because I tried running the program in the VS debugger (I suspected as much). When I build the release version and ran it, it works.